# Unix substitute multiple strings using a reference file

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a reference file and using that I want to replace multiple files in a directory. I am using AWK GSUB for that, however it is not replacing exact word, but replacing all occurrences. How can I stop that behaviour? How can I replace just the word? in this case the word is "IT"

My reference file

```
$ cat dev_to_prod.config

nonprod_DATA_PATH PROD_DATA_PATH
nonprod_ENCRYPTKEY PROD_ENCRYPTKEY
IT Business
```

My current data file

```
$ cat filefile.txt
IT
WITH
/IT/DFGh/erfe
/WITH/IT/sjfgh/hjIT/dfdsf/ITvjkl
```

Output with current code

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$2;next}{for(i in A)gsub(i,A[i])}1' dev_to_prod.config file.txt
Business
WBusinessH
/Business/DFGh/erfe
/WBusinessH/Business/sjfgh/hjBusiness/dfdsf/Businessvjkl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man awk` says:

> ```
> \<     matches the empty string at the beginning of a word.
> \>     matches the empty string at the end of a word.
> ```

Then would you please try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$2;next}{for(i in A)gsub("\\<"i"\\>",A[i])}1' dev_to_prod.config file.txt
```

Output:

```
Business
WITH
/Business/DFGh/erfe
/WITH/Business/sjfgh/hjIT/dfdsf/ITvjkl
```

Comment: Thank you. I read in the man, but I was not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works. The regex implementation in awk may be a little weired when combining a fixed pattern and a variable.